# Responsive Bootstrap3 Modal Textarea Not working in iOS

Tags: ios, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I created a vanilla Bootstrap 3.1.1 Modal (http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals) example for the purposes of illustrating my own feedback-form problems on an iPhone 3GS (iOS 6.1)

Example JSBin: http://jsbin.com/UFoRIYex/628/edit

Here's what it looks like in the iOS Simulator (iPhone 3GS iOS 6.1):

[image: Example Modal Form]

The problem I'm having, is, as soon as you try to enter text into the feedback form, the keyboard overlay hides all of the input text.

[image: Example Modal Form with Keyboard out]

Is there a work around for this?

Comment: One thing I did notice, this works fine on iOS 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may help resolve the problem:
http://www.abeautifulsite.net/blog/2013/11/bootstrap-3-modals-and-the-ios-virtual-keyboard/